# Dynamically assign object a name Typescript

Tags: typescript

Ok So I want my object to be dynamically named something like this

```js
 private prepareEntityMarkerInfo(markerObj: any) {

       let infoValues = markerObj.infoIdentities[1]
       var cid = markerObj.infoIdentities[1].getDataColumnIdentity()[0].getColumnInfo().getColumnID();
       
       var Obj1 = { 
   
             cid: {
              columnName:[infoValues.getDataColumnIdentity()[0].getColumnInfo().getColumnName()] ,
              columnValue: [infoValues.getDisplayVal()]
            }
          }
         
        };
```

I want the cid inside Obj1 to be changed whenever theres a new value. So for that I defined it outside Obj1 then called it inside Obj1.

But when i hover on var cid it says that cid is decalred but never used, but I am using it inside Obj1.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: And how exactly it is used? I don't see the place where `cid` is on right side of some expression.

Comment: @Cerberus I want to use it such that I can generate each cid based on the columnID saved on database

Comment: You're trying to use it as key, so you could later ask for `Obj1[cid]`, right?

Comment: @Cerberus hi i just posted the way i figured maybe it can help you understand my situationbetter

Answer (score 0):

not that its important but if anyone wants to to do it future i was able to do like this

```js
   private prepareEntityMarkerInfo(markerObj: any) {

        let infoValues = markerObj.infoIdentities[1]
        var Obj1 = {
            [markerObj.infoIdentities[1].getDataColumnIdentity()[0].getColumnInfo().getColumnId()]: {
                columnName: [infoValues.getDataColumnIdentity()[0].getColumnInfo().getColumnName()],
                columnValue: [infoValues.getDisplayVal()]
            }
        }

    };
```

Instead of defining cid above I was able to put its value into [] and place it as a name of object.

Sorry for such a weird question

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use the `cid` variable just as you've used the expression for it:

```
 private prepareEntityMarkerInfo(markerObj: any) {

       let infoValues = markerObj.infoIdentities[1];
       var cid = markerObj.infoIdentities[1].getDataColumnIdentity()[0].getColumnInfo().getColumnID();

       var Obj1 = { 
            [cid]: {
              columnName:[infoValues.getDataColumnIdentity()[0].getColumnInfo().getColumnName()] ,
              columnValue: [infoValues.getDisplayVal()]
           }
     }

};
```